# NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate

Tags: jsf, glassfish, ejb, hazelcast

im using Hazelcast HttpSession Clustering with two Glassfish 3.1.2.2 instance. Im using `@EJB` or @Inject annotation to inject EJB(s) in managed beans. In `@ViewScoped` and `@SessionScoped` managed beans, im getting

```
com.hazelcast.nio.HazelcastSerializationException:
 java.io.NotSerializableException: 
  com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate Exception.
```

When i marked the `@EJB` field with transient keyword, hence, i didnt get `SerializationException`. But, after deserialization, my ejbs didnt re-inject and then, im getting a `NullPointerException`.

How can i handle this problem? (Note: Hazel vers: 2.4)

Comment: Hi, was you able to solve it? Having the same issue with `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate Exception` and can not find any solution so far. All what is posted below - already implemented... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making your EJB classes implement Serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Besides your EJB classes, make sure **all objects nested** in them are Serializable as well.

There's a VM option to add details to the exception. It will show the root and nested classes failing to serialize and help you figure out what you're missing:

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

---

You might also want to check that you define **serialVersionUID** for every Serializable class includding **superclasses** (if they're Serializable)

Note: your code may run without serialVersionUID sometimes but [read the last paragraph in Serializable's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to understand why it will be a problem depending on the environment.